# Looping monthly indices for a particular year

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a data format like attached image below where we are having sales figures of different SKUs for multiple years, distributed monthly.

[image: Input file format]

I have calculated monthly indices for each year using the function;

```
calc_monthly_all<- function(X){
  X$sku <- as.character(X$sku)
  X$Yearly_Avg <- rowMeans(X[,-c(1:2)])
  level_one <- X %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Month_')), funs(./Yearly_Avg))
  return(level_one)
  }
```

The data displayed is read as 'df_data' in R, & after applying the function, output is like below,

```
> calc_monthly_all(df_data)
             sku Year  Month_Jan  Month_Feb Month_March Month_April Month_May Month_June Month_July Month_Aug Month_Sept
1 10929000284004 2015 0.32601608 0.19821778   0.6755053   2.0838948 0.5398826  1.7657031  1.2414692 1.1136709  0.6650728
2 10929000284004 2016 0.92209048 2.52811562   1.4961071   1.8380744 0.6534019  0.7511068  0.5190576 0.2992214  0.1038115
3 10929001124004 2014 0.04678503 0.04318618   0.4847649   0.9385797 0.9781670  0.9353407  0.7924664 1.2894674  1.2070537
4 10929001124004 2015 1.40699537 1.86480849   0.7979080   0.7520179 0.3975936  1.1719218  0.4233502 0.6419178  1.5749569
5 10929001124004 2016 0.92209048 2.52811562   1.4961071   1.8380744 0.6534019  0.7511068  0.5190576 0.2992214  0.1038115
6 10929001124104 2016 1.00160192 0.65078094   0.8191163   0.8358030 1.0112802  0.9419971  0.7209318 1.0449873  1.0337071
7 10929001124104 2017 0.83334681 0.74955923   0.7739514   1.2059589 1.1626741  1.4993773  1.0948676 0.9872054  1.1436520
  Month_Oct Month_Nov Month_Dec Yearly_Avg
1 1.5831341 1.1945229 0.6129102   3834.167
2 1.2029922 0.5434838 1.1425373   1637.583
3 2.2273273 1.7357246 1.3211372  27786.667
4 0.9569818 0.6437317 1.3678164  55131.667
5 1.2029922 0.5434838 1.1425373   1637.583
6 1.3110399 1.3426111 1.2861434 149820.000
7 0.9806706 0.8718438 0.6968927 154557.500
```

Now, for each year of each SKU, we got the monthly indices. Now we need to take the indices for one particular year, let's say for first year. That means for each SKU, we will take monthly indices for their respective first year, return the data frame containing only first year's monthly indices for each SKU. For that I tried;

```
calc_monthly_fys<- function(X){
  X$sku <- as.character(X$sku)
  X$Yearly_Avg <- rowMeans(X[,-c(1:2)])
  level_one <- X %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Month_')), funs(./Yearly_Avg))
  first_yr_store <- data.frame()
  for (i in unique(level_one$sku)){
    fys1 <- subset(level_one,sku %in% i)
    fys <- fys1[1,]
    df <-data.frame(fys)
    df_total <- rbind(first_yr_store,df)
    return(df_total)
  }
}
```

but, It's not giving proper result, only first SKU is appearing.

```
calc_monthly_fys(df_data)
             sku Year Month_Jan Month_Feb Month_March Month_April Month_May Month_June Month_July Month_Aug Month_Sept
1 10929000284004 2015 0.3260161 0.1982178   0.6755053    2.083895 0.5398826   1.765703   1.241469  1.113671  0.6650728
  Month_Oct Month_Nov Month_Dec Yearly_Avg
1  1.583134  1.194523 0.6129102   3834.167
```

I need this for all SKUs.

Here the example is having 3 unique SKUs, but data may have 'n' number of SKU. Finally the output I need should be in below format;

[image: Final Table output]

The names of the columns, (SKU_1 to SKU_N) should come dynamically (If we have four unique SKUs, that four SKU names should appear as the column names). `_FYI` indicates here 'First Year Index', I think we may use `paste` function to attach the suffix `_FYI` after each unique SKU name in the final output table.

Please help me to generate monthly indices in the discussed format for N number of SKUs & M number of years.

TIA

Comment: ` It's not giving proper result, only first SKU is appearing.` - I think that's mainly because you have a `return()` inside your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear how you want to treat the different years for each SKU, but this might help.

It assumes `df` contains what you've shown as the result of your `calc_monthly_all(df_data)` call.

```
# Get rid of the yearly average, as it's not needed in the results
df$Yearly_Avg <- NULL

# We're going to transpose the dataframe  (turn the rows into columns,
# and the columns into rows), so make the row names what will be the 
# column names
rownames(df) <- paste0(df$sku, '_', df$Year)

# Get rid of the unnecessary sku and year columns, as they're not needed
# if we leave them, the transpose will coerce all the columns to characters
df$sku <- NULL
df$Year <- NULL

# Transpose the dataframe
df2 <- t(df)

# Get rid of "Month_" at the start of the rownames
rownames(df2) <- gsub('^Month_', '', rownames(df2))

# View the results
df2
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment and your previous code, the function would be something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

calc_monthly_all<- function(X){
  X$sku <- as.character(X$sku)
  X$Yearly_Avg <- rowMeans(X[,-c(1:2)])
  level_one <- X %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Month_')), funs(./Yearly_Avg))

  level_one$Yearly_Avg <- NULL

  rownames(level_one) <- paste0(level_one$sku, '_', level_one$Year)
  level_one$sku <- NULL
  level_one$Year <- NULL

  result <- t(level_one)
  rownames(result) <- gsub('^Month_', '', rownames(result))
  result
}
```

**EDIT 2**
If you just want data for a single year, you would filter in the function before doing the transpose:

```
library(dplyr)

calc_monthly_one_year<- function(X, required_year){
  X <- X %>% filter(Year == required_year)

  X$sku <- as.character(X$sku)
  X$Yearly_Avg <- rowMeans(X[,-c(1:2)])
  level_one <- X %>% dplyr::mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Month_')), funs(./Yearly_Avg))

  level_one$Yearly_Avg <- NULL

  rownames(level_one) <- level_one$sku
  level_one$sku <- NULL
  level_one$Year <- NULL

  result <- t(level_one)
  rownames(result) <- gsub('^Month_', '', rownames(result))
  result
}

calc_monthly_one_year(df_data, 2016)
```

Comment: sorry I could not understand it properly. Without the 'return' statement, the function output is coming 'NULL'.
The answer you have provided, should be inside the for loop. But where are you taking the first year indices for each SKU? I need to use the entire process inside a function, so when data will be fed, I will only get the final output according to the last format attached

Comment: No, the answer I provided is separate to the for loop.  It uses the results of `calc_monthly_all` as displayed at the top of your question.  It doesn't use `calc_monthly_fys` (or the for loop) at all

Comment: Really well explained. I was thinking of loop only but it can be done with simpler method like yours. Thanks a lot @Hobo

Comment: No worries; happy to help